# best_in_place nil and edit functions not working on rails4 with bootstrap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, best-in-place

I used the gem in a project before, only it was rails 3 with no css framework. Now it seems like jQuery functions for best_in_place are eather blocked or not loaded at all. There's no placeholder visible from :nil function and no editing current values available neither.

This is my view partial:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <%= best_in_place [@company,service], :name, type: :input, :nil => "Click to fill" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <%= best_in_place [@company,service], :duration, type: :input, :nil => "Click to   fill" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <%= link_to 'X', [@company,service], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @service.update(service_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { respond_with_bip(@service) }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

service.js.coffee for activating jquery best_in_place functions

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

And application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require_tree
```

I noticed also the last update on best_in_place is from 02/2013, so maybe it's not fully compatible with my present project. If that's the case i'd appreciate any data on similar gems to be used instead.

Edit:

It's clearly a javascript issue but i can't figure it out. I get the following error on my browser console:

```
"undefined is not a function".
```

Only it points at jquery.js line 10306, which is empty ..

Comment: btw, i see no javascript errors on the browser's console. Only some .css issues.

Comment: It seems even in the demo it's not working? Should one not be able to edit country here?: http://bipapp.heroku.com/users/186

Comment: at least I can confirm that best_in_place works with rails 4.2 - otherwise our app would be completely broken. We rely heavily on it. Just be sure to use bip > 3.0.0. Also I see commits from Feb 19th, are we talking about https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems, like you forgot add class `.best_in_place`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="best_in_place col-lg-4">
    <%= best_in_place [@company,service], :name, type: :input, :nil => "Click to fill" %>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
...........
```